# Why don't Alkyl Fluorides form Grignard Reagents

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

The reactivity of forming Grignards reagent were given as RI > RBr > RCl > RF and was noted that Grignard reagent with alkyl fluorides cannot be formed. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Consider the strength of the C-F bond compared to the other C-Hal bonds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Waylander, the greater strength of the carbon-fluorine bond versus other carbon-halogen bonds raises the activation energy for obtaining a Grignard reagent with fluorine. A secondary issue is that if you do run a Grignard-reagent synthesis using a fluoride, you may complicate the workup by forming magnesium fluoride precipitate or (especially hazardous and glass-corrosive) hydrofluoric acid. For both reasons it is more feasible in most applications to use a halogen that is easier to work with.

Fluoride Grignard reagents can be made by first using dioxane and heating to promote the disproportionation of a heavier-halide Grignard reagent forming the dialkyl magnesium compound ($\ce{2RMgX <=> R2Mg + MgX2}$; see [Cope[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01314a059)) followed by reaction of the dialkylmagnesium compound with appropriate fluorine compounds (see [Ashby and Nackashi[2]](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-328X(00)82011-2)).

1. Arthur C. Cope (1935). "The Preparation of Dialkylmagnesium Compounds from Grignard Reagents". *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **57**, 11, 2238–2240.
   https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01314a059.
2. E.C. Ashby, John Nackashi (1974).
   "The preparation of organomagnesium fluorides by organometallic exchange reactions".
   *Journal of Organometallic Chemistry*,
   **72**, 1, 11-20.
   ISSN 0022-328X,
   https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-328X(00)82011-2.

Comment: A third reason - alkyl chlorides/bromides/iodides are generally easier to form/more widely available than alkyl fluorides

Answer (score 1):

Grignard reagents where the halogen is fluorine was previously not taken into interest owing to the unreactive nature of the carbon-fluorine bond and the preparation of such species was very time and resource consuming. Until recently, chemists looked for ways to create this species:

1. Using specially activated magnesium (Rieke metals)
2. Organometallic exchange reactions (See @OscarLanzi's answer especially the 2nd paper)
3. Selective direct fluorination ([Deyoung et.al., **1992**](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1992/c3/c39920000811/unauth))
4. Mechanochemical activation ([Speight et. al, **2020**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7037680/))